# ABAP string to SHA256 different to SAPUI5/Javascript

Tags: javascript, abap, sha256, hmac

Currently on my SAPUI5 project, I am creating a HMAC encoded string with this line of code:

```
var secretKey = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('SECRETKEY'); //USING THE CRYPTOJS LIBRARY!
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256('abc', secretKey);
hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
```

which gives `eZdbNMwgWKOANEiozokNG2FGfzI7Yy/B8IQKXr3+krY=`

I am using the CryptoJS library to execute this code in UI5.

However the problem is that I am receiving the wrong HMAC encoded string when I want to do the same in ABAP. After testing a few times, it seems like the encoding (in abap) is wrong before the HMAC is calculated.

Is there a function module that does 'CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse()' - after googling what it does it interprets the parameter as encoded and converts it into a word array:

```
DATA:
  lv_sign_key_x                TYPE xstring,
  lv_hmac_result               TYPE string.

DATA(lv_binary_secret) = cl_abap_hmac=>string_to_xstring('SECRETKEY').

cl_abap_hmac=>calculate_hmac_for_char(
  EXPORTING
    if_algorithm           = 'SHA256'           "Hash Algorithm
    if_key                 = lv_binary_secret   "HMAC Key
    if_data                = 'abc'   "Data
  IMPORTING
    ef_hmacb64string       = lv_hmac_result  "HMAC value as base64-encoded string
).
```

which gives `9dyEZn5G+uiRwsNqgY5S6k9/gmCheFNF4vFa5qBKK1w=`

Comment: Hi @SandraRossi the result for SECRETKEY IN JAVA is 
words: Array(2)
0: 305419896
1: 0
In SAP, it shows it's hexadecimal value which is 313233343536373839

Comment: @SandraRossi Javascript* Tried doing hmac_for_raw and gave a completely different string output.

Comment: Are you giving the results in base64 corresponding to the code above? I don't have the same result in ABAP: `9dyEZn5G+uiRwsNqgY5S6k9/gmCheFNF4vFa5qBKK1w=`

Comment: @SandraRossi I am also getting the same 9dyEZn5G+uiRwsNqgY5S6k9/gmCheFNF4vFa5qBKK1w= however it is wrong as the javascript version is eZdbNMwgWKOANEiozokNG2FGfzI7Yy/B8IQKXr3+krY=

Comment: Also asked in [SCN](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12731774/abap-string-to-sha256-different-to-sapui5javascrip.html) and **answered there**.

Answer (score 0):

Shows exact way to encode to hex and calculate to HMAC256. [Link](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12731774/abap-string-to-sha256-different-to-sapui5javascrip.html)

```
data lv_binary_secret type xstring.
data lv_string type string value '48656c6c6f2c20576f726c6421'.
translate lv_string to upper case.
lv_binary_secret = lv_string.


cl_abap_hmac=>calculate_hmac_for_char(
  EXPORTING
    if_algorithm           = 'SHA256'           "Hash Algorithm
    if_key                 = lv_binary_secret   "HMAC Key
    if_data                = 'abc'   "Data
  IMPORTING
    ef_hmacb64string       = data(lv_hmac_result)  "HMAC value as base64-encoded string
).`enter code here`
```

Comment: Please [provide context for links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), i.e. explain the reason of the issue, how the code solves it. Moreover, your answer is confusing because `LV_STRING` contains the hexadecimal representation of UTF-8 encoding of **`Hello: World!`** while you had `SECRETKEY` (I guess it should be '5345435245544B4559' to match your question).